# How to use variable in 'LIKE field var%' in MySql query of Spring Boot?

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot

I wrote this code in spring boot repository to get clientInfo according to the user provided status and starting with certain value entered by user in front-end search panel. But the LIKE ':nameFilter%' part in the query is not being executed correctly and the query is returning null.
How can I make it work?

```
@SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM ClientInfo WHERE status = :status AND name LIKE ':nameFilter%' ORDER BY createdAt DESC LIMIT 10 OFFSET :page")
    @RegisterBeanMapper(ClientInfo.class)
    public List<ClientInfo> getClientInfoByStatusDESC(@Bind int page,String status,String orderBy,String nameFilter);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try `CONCAT` a function of MySQL for combining query param with others.

`LIKE CONCAT(:name, '%')`

Comment: @Ashish I'm happy to help. I appreciate if you upvote or check the awswer

Comment: I up voted your answer but it says **Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.**

Comment: @Ashish it's okay because I received the points. Thanks man!

Answer (score 0):

You just need to remove single quotes from LIKE statement:

```
@SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM ClientInfo WHERE status = :status AND name LIKE :nameFilter% ORDER BY createdAt DESC LIMIT 10 OFFSET :page")
```

Comment: tried removing quote but got this error instead "=Internal Server Error, status=500).
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'ORDER BY createdAt DESC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0' at line 1"